# Setting Folder Properties in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm writing some VBA code at the moment and part of the requirements is to set the security on the folder.

`FileSystemObject` doesn't do the job. I can set the attributes of the folder to read-only but that is it as far as I am aware.

`ADsSecurity` would do the job nicely, but I cannot seem to find any examples for anything other than VBS or VB6, certainly nothing for VBA. I have managed to locate the DLL and installed and registered it but I am still getting an error stating that the ActiveX component can't create object. This for both late and early binding.

I have also tried to use ACL information, but that just crashes out Excel when trying to get the file security descriptor.

Does anyone out there have any other thoughts?

Comment: How have you registered the COM-DLL? Have you used regsvr32 or regasm? Is the DLL a valid COM - DLL at all? Be also aware of being off-topic here, go better to StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you meaning the ADsSecurity.dll?

Yes opened cmd as administrator and put the dll in c:\windows\syswow64
I then ran Regsvr32 from in the cmd window and it said that it registered all ok.

Where do I go in Stack?  I thought this was??

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/ :) And this is a SuperUser actually

Comment: First hit [How to use Visual Basic and ADsSecurity.dll to properly order ACEs in an ACL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269159). Besides that consider extending your title to include you're trying to do it in VBA and supply code you've given a shot so far.

Comment: We do accept VBa questions here, but, only if the focus of the question/script is Excel - this isn't really about Excel as it's about file permissions, as such I think SO is a better suit for you :)

Comment: Thanks Dave....sorry I hadn't realised...I will head over to SO :)